# OpenDKIM set d=[senderServer.com] tag to use the default sender server instead the FROM email domain

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

Here is the issue:

I have an email server with OpenDKIM and Postfix installed as here: 
http://www.serveridol.com/2012/02/17/opendkim-configuring-dkim-keys-on-postfix/

My TXT DNS record is on the main domain (Server domain name)
Here: senderServer.com

It works great when I send an email from senderServer.com using my FROM address as: anything@**senderServer.com**

The problem is when I send an email using my FROM address as: anything@**otherDomain.com**

The DKIM signature is added but using otherDomain as the domain value tag:

`DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
    d=otherDomain.com; s=20131125; t=1385596727;
    bh=g3zLYH4xKxcPrHOD18z9YfpQcnk/GaJedfustWU5uGs=;
    h=Date:To:Subject:From;
    b=ujfsdhfu9hf9sdfs9df9sfs9fhsd9hfsfnsvkjnsdlvljsv`

so, the server that is receiving the messages is not finding the DNS record which is obviously clear since the **d=** tag value is otherDomain.com instead senderServer.com

I would like to find the way to retrieve the d= value from the server name instead retrieve it from the FROM header email address... or override it to be always **d=senderServer.com**

Answer (score 0):

```
Domain *
KeyFile /etc/postfix/dkim.key
Selector mail
```

in `/etc/opendkim.conf` to use the same key for multiple domains ( [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM#Common_errors_and_fixes) )

and added `no_milters` to `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

made this line:

`-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks`

look like:

```
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
```

This prevented opendkim signing messages twice.

Comment: This answer does not work. Sure it will use the same key but it will still put d=otherDomain.com in the header.